# Limit Dns.GetHostAddresses by time

Tags: c#, system.net

i'm writing a script that resolve ip address for domain using `C#`

the problem is that i have a lot of domains that does not resolve to an IP, so the code (`Dns.GetHostAddresses`) is running for a long time trying to resolve an IP for a domain that doesn't have an IP.

this is the code:

```
public string getIPfromHost(string host)
{
    try
    {
        var domain = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[0];
        return domain.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "No IP";
    }
}
```

what i want to do is if there is no IP after 1 sec i want to return "No IP"

how can i achieve that?

Comment: Yes, that exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by using TPL(Task Parallel Library). You can create new task and wait for 1 sec, if it is succeed then return true otherwise false.
just use below code in `getIPfromHost(string host)` this method.
**(This is solution for your question which needs to wait for 1 sec please ensure your previous method was working fine.)**

```
public string getIPfromHost(string host)
        {
            try
            {
                Task<string> task = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                     var domain = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[0];
                     return domain.ToString();
                });

            bool success = task.Wait(1000);
            if (success)
            {
                return task.Result;
            }
            else
            {
                return "No IP";
            }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return "No IP";
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the [`Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostaddressesasync) method can be used instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`:

```
public string getIPfromHost(string host)
{
    try
    {
        var domain = Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync(host)[0];
        bool isTaskComplete = domain.Wait(1000);
        if (isTaskComplete)
        {
            return domain.Result.ToString();
        }
        else // Task timed out
        {
            return "No IP";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "No IP";
    }
}
```